# Values from class into variable

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I have got 2 classes, one that's called MineField and one that's called Options, in the options-class there is scales that i get the values from through a function inside that class, def assign():, the MineField-class have three parameters (w,h,m). I want to assign values to these parameters from the scales in the Options-class. (I use tkinter)

```
Class Options:
  def __init__(self, w, h, m)
    ...
    minorinput = Scale.(...)   
    mainloop()
    ...
  def assign():
    self.width = widthinput.get()
    self.height = heightinput.get()
    self.minor = minorinput.get()

def main():
  ins = Options(0,0,0)
  ins.assign()
  w = ins.width
  h = ins.height
  m = ins.minor
  game.MineField(w,h,m)
```

So how do I get these values from the scales into game.MineField?

Comment: You want to store w, h and m in the minefield class?

Comment: err... you just did, by passing them as parameters?

Comment: Are you wanting to be able to change the values while in the middle of a game, ie when self.width is changed, Minefield gets notified of the change? That would be a Publish-Subscribe pattern.

Comment: I don't need to change the values mid-game, and yes, I need to store width, height and minor from Options-class into game.Minefield(w,h,m) and store width in w height in h, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is highly unusual. In essence, you can't do what you are asking to do. At least, not in the way you're trying to do it.

Are you aware that once you call `mainloop`, the remainder of your code after that statement won't run until you destroy your window? Once the window is destroyed, you can't query the widgets for their values since they don't exist.

Comment: So what do you suggest? What happends if I withdraw the Options-window?

Comment: I want the widgets to "hold" their values (at least until I've created the game.MineField-object). Does "withdraw" work this way?

Comment: @tivon: the way you've structured your code, you can't possibly create the MineField object until the Options class has been destroyed (because its constructor starts an infinite loop by calling `mainloop`, which only terminates when the window is destroyed). Once Options has been destroyed, the values will no longer be accessible. You need to re-architect your solution.

Comment: What happends if I put the scales inside the MineField class? By creating a function inside that class that creates the Options window. Wouldn't that work?